# Please spot the error in my Python code

Tags: python, if-statement

I have to code for a trouble shooting system, which uses keywords in the user input to provide a solution from a text file. I have a list of If statements, which directs the program to read specific lines from a textile and present them as solutions according to the specific Keywords present in the user input.

However, whatever the user input is, the program seems to display the first two lines in the text file (the program seems to be stuck on the first if statement).

```
Keywords = ['screen', 'display', 'audio', 'sound',]
Keywords2 = ['cracked', 'broken', 'water', 'frozen', 'unresponsive']

# Collecting the user's problem using user input

problem = input(str("Please enter your problem:")).split()# Assigns the user input to the variable 'progarm' and converts the user input into a string

# Presenting solutions to user if corresponding Keywords are present in the users input 'problem'
if any(i in Keywords or Keywords2 for i in problem): # This while loop checks that any of the keywords (i) in the lists (Keyword or Keywords2) are present in the user's input (problem), which has been splitted into individual words (indicated by spacing - i)
    if Keywords[0] or Keywords[1] and Keywords2[0] or Keywords2[1] in problem:
        read(0)
        read(1)
    elif Keywords[0] or Keywords[1] and Keywords2[3] or Keywords2[4] in problem:
        read(3)
    elif Keywords2[2] in problem:
        read(2)
    elif Keywords[2] or Keywords[3] and Keywords2[5] or Keywords2[6] in problem:
        read(4)
        read(0)
```

When I enter 'the phone fell in water', it should detect the Keyword 'water', which is Keywords2[2], and read the second line in the text file. Instead, it reads the lines directed in the first if statement.

```
Please enter your problem:My phone fell into water
Get it repaired at a reliable repair shop

You will need to buy a new screen and a new screen protector
```

Any suggestions to improve the code and make it work would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your if/else statements don't behave like you think they do, look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42888758/python-if-else-defers-to-wrong-branch/42888878#42888878

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be with the improper usage of `in`.

You may want to do something like this:

```
any(i in Keywords or i in Keywords2 for i in problem)
```

instead of

```
any(i in Keywords or Keywords2 for i in problem)
```

Similarly, for the inner `if` and `elif` statements.

For example:

```
if (Keywords[0] in problem or Keywords[1] in problem) and (Keywords2[0] in problem or Keywords2[1] in problem):
```

instead of

```
if Keywords[0] or Keywords[1] and Keywords2[0] or Keywords2[1] in problem:
```

Comment: Good answer, you're doing fine.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Don't worry, you're not violating any rules. As a sidenote: If you select your code and hit the `{}` button it will automatically format it for you :)

Comment: thank you @Keiwan. I will make use of your advice from now on :D